# echarts - custom toolbox feature does not work

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I 'm trying to add a custom toolbox feature to an echart and I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bind must be called on a function
    at bind (<anonymous>)
    at echarts.js:80214:30
    at each (echarts.js:423:24)
    at createIconPaths (echarts.js:80158:11)
    at DataDiffer.processFeature (echarts.js:80104:11)
    at DataDiffer._performRestAdd (echarts.js:30822:31)
    at DataDiffer._executeOneToOne (echarts.js:30739:14)
    at DataDiffer.execute (echarts.js:30702:79)
    at ToolboxView.render (echarts.js:80047:143)
    at echarts.js:29722:27
```

The feature I'm trying to add is the following:

```
myTool1: {
  show: true,
  title: 'custom method',
  icon: 'path://M432.45,595.444c0,2.177-4.661,6.82-11.305,6.82c-6.475,0-11.306-4.567-11.306-6.82s4.852-6.812,11.306-6.812C427.841,588.632,432.452,593.191,432.45,595.444L432.45,595.444z M421.155,589.876c-3.009,0-5.448,2.495-5.448,5.572s2.439,5.572,5.448,5.572c3.01,0,5.449-2.495,5.449-5.572C426.604,592.371,424.165,589.876,421.155,589.876L421.155,589.876z M421.146,591.891c-1.916,0-3.47,1.589-3.47,3.549c0,1.959,1.554,3.548,3.47,3.548s3.469-1.589,3.469-3.548C424.614,593.479,423.062,591.891,421.146,591.891L421.146,591.891zM421.146,591.891',
  onclick: function () {
                    alert('myTool1')
           }
}
```

It looks like that the onclick feature option is not passed correctly to the featureManager in echarts.

Has anyone experienced something similar? Any idea how to solve this?

I'm using echarts version 5.3.2

Answer (score 1):

outSide function;

```js
alertFun():void {
  alert('myTool1')
}
```

Echarts

```
myTool1: {
  show: true,
  title: 'custom method',
  icon: 'path://M432.45,595.444c0,2.177-4.661,6.82-11.305,6.82c-6.475,0-11.306-4.567-11.306-6.82s4.852-6.812,11.306-6.812C427.841,588.632,432.452,593.191,432.45,595.444L432.45,595.444z M421.155,589.876c-3.009,0-5.448,2.495-5.448,5.572s2.439,5.572,5.448,5.572c3.01,0,5.449-2.495,5.449-5.572C426.604,592.371,424.165,589.876,421.155,589.876L421.155,589.876z M421.146,591.891c-1.916,0-3.47,1.589-3.47,3.549c0,1.959,1.554,3.548,3.47,3.548s3.469-1.589,3.469-3.548C424.614,593.479,423.062,591.891,421.146,591.891L421.146,591.891zM421.146,591.891',
  onclick: () => this.alertFun()
}
```